# Windows clipboard manager with support of copy by select and paste by middle-mouse

Tags: windows, mouse, clipboard

I'm looking for a clipboard manager for MS Windows which would support the X.org way of copy/pasting by selecting/middle-mouse-button-clicking.

Preferably free/open-source.

Answer (score 1):

If someone won't post better answer, I would post this workaround so you can have at least something:

1. install [3D Clipboard](http://3dclipboard.com/) manager (freeware) and run it **with Administrator privileges** (otherwise it cannot catch hotkeys)
2. in program options, set **AutoPaste** to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> (and test if it opens clipboard history)
3. set up AutoHotKey (some basics are given [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22220666/in-notepad-change-tab-size-instantly/22880354#22880354))
4. define AutoHotKey macro `mbutton::^!+j` (it means that pressing middle mouse button (`mbutton`) sends (`::`) the above key shortcut (`^!+j`))

I have tested it, it works fine!

Comment: Thank you for that tip. Although this will "just" show clipboard history under cursor, it's better than nothing. It would be nice to write AutoHotKey macro that would copy selected text after left mouse button release (not click), but I'm not sure if AutoHotKey is capable of doing that.

Comment: @meridius - button release can be mapped for sure. the only thing is whether you wish to send Ctrl+C ONLY if there was also dragging action before release (i.e. mouse movement while left button was down) or not.  checking that condition might be more difficult, but I think it is possible without any special hacking. anyway, there will still remain small problem: if you drag&drop some file, copying will occur when you release the button. I can imagine making Ctrl+C only if there is a window message that text selection is completed, but I am not sure if such a message exists - I did not find it

Comment: I was thinking of the same sort of workaround, ***but*** I strongly recommend [Ditto clipboard manager](http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net) there is nothing that comes close to it for gratis Windows clipboard apps