# Autotype Windows clipboard contents (password) into webpage that blocks Paste

Tags: windows, clipboard

I need a simple utility that can "type" (*not* paste) the contents of the Clipboard. I want to copy a password from a Password Manager tool to the Windows Clipboard, then use this utility to "type" the password into web forms that prohibit use of the `Paste` command.

**Requirements:**

- Free/gratis
- Invoked with a hotkey (e.g. Win+Ctrl+V)
- Must **not** retain Clipboard content
- Compatible with Windows 7 and later

**Use case:**

I use a Password Manager that can auto-type a username and password into web page logon forms. But when changing passwords on a site, one usually needs to type the old password once followed by the new password twice. My Password Manager can do this but changing between the two types of auto-type behavior requires a bit too many setting changes just for changing a password on oddball sites that block Paste.

- I saw [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14427/software-that-brings-auto-complete-everywhere/19998#19998) but it asks for something that will keep a history. Same problem with [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3032/windows-clipboard-manager-with-support-of-copy-by-select-and-paste-by-middle-mou).
- [This](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/27981/tool-that-allows-pasting-clipboard-by-iterating-over-contents-and-emulating-key) is closer but it asks about "iterating over the clipboard contents" which I don't want to do.

Comment: A perhaps more direct way to thwart a page that attempts to prevent pasting is to use Firefox's debugger. You can paste your test directly into the DOM.

Comment: Most password managers auto-type using `{USERNAME}{TAB}{PASSWORD}{ENTER}` sequence. Maybe you can configure your password manager to output only `{PASSWORD}`. [KeePass](https://keepass.info) can do this. Also useful on sites that remember your username and hence only require to fill passwords.

Comment: @VlastimilOvčáčík Yes, I can change the sequence of keystrokes my password manager sends, but it's inconvenient.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you need to do this only once and that you can have multiple sequences for one credential, so when you trigger auto-type the password manager opens [this popup](http://weblog.patrice.ch/files/images/2011/keepass-autotype.png) to choose what autotype sequence you want. Anyway if the one time setup is too much trouble (maybe because you have lot of credentials like this) then your answer below is probably best.

Comment: @VlastimilOvčáčík My password manager does not give me the option you describe. If you want, post an answer recommending this password manager!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can accomplish this with an [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/) script. According to their website:

> AutoHotkey is a free, open-source scripting language for Windows that allows users to easily create small to complex scripts for all kinds of tasks such as: form fillers, auto-clicking, macros, etc.

In your case, install AutoHotKey, save the following script into a plain text file named something like `AutoType.ahk`, then double-click the script to activate it:

```
SendMode Input    
^#v::
    SendInput, {Raw}%ClipBoard%
Return
```

The `^#v::` string instructs AHK to wait until the user presses <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, then the `SendInput` command is run which quickly types the *exact* content of the Clipboard, character by character. This sends the Clipboard text wherever the cursor is, so be sure to put the cursor in the correct field before pressing the hotkey sequence.

It's free, compatible with all versions of Windows, and doesn't save the Clipboard content in any way.

Answer (score 1):

[KeePass](https://keepass.info) can be configured with multiple auto-type sequences. By using this feature you can

- fight *paste blocking* sites

  - during login
  - during changing password, double checking new password
- multi-step login sites (like Google)
- fill sudo prompts
- etc.

Most password managers auto-type by using `{USERNAME}{TAB}{PASSWORD}{ENTER}` sequence. Additionally to this sequence you can define simpler one `{PASSWORD}` that is more useful during above described use-cases.

## Use Case

#### 1. registration

[image]

#### 2. auto-type one time configuration

[image]

#### 3. login

- fire up auto-type operation by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>
- keepass will find proper credential by matching title of focused window with database records
- with multiple matches, or multiple autotype sequences it will present popup:
- the pop only requires one click

[image]